# to get always current href attribute by more clicks jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, get, attributes, href

in my example i have three a-Tags. **First Step:** If i click on the first a-tag so i get in the console the current href attribute from the a-tag. **Second Step:** If i click on the second a-tag so i get not the current href attribute. Hmm why?

I need that for my solution. I will get the href attribute from the a-tag and post this in "Yes" button in the modal Window message.

Here my HTML Example Code:

```
<a data-featherlight="#fl1" href="www.google.com" id="delArea" class="btn btn_red"  title="Veranstaltungsort löschen">delete</a>

<a data-featherlight="#fl1" href="www.yahoo.com" id="delArea" class="btn btn_red" title="Veranstaltungsort löschen">delete</a>

<a data-featherlight="#fl1" href="www.bing.com" id="delArea" class="btn btn_red"  title="Veranstaltungsort löschen">delete</a>


    <div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
        <h2>Delete Item</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <strong>Are you Sure?</strong><br>
                blub blub?
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">

            <a class="btn btn_gray no text_none" id="close_button">No</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn_red text_none">Yes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here my jQuery Code:

```
//Close button featherlight
jQuery(document).on('click','#close_button',function(){

    jQuery('.featherlight').click();
});

// Get href link
jQuery('#delArea').click(function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    console.log(link);
});
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe79f/2/)**

Comment: Id's have to be unique. Add `delArea` as a class, change your selector to `.delArea` and your problem is gone - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xe79f/3/)

Comment: @Andreas thank you. I will solve with this logic. I know that id should be unique